# Counting the amount of rows per value and plotting them in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I have been trying to calculate the species richness by altitude for this dataset of birds that has 33,391 observations and 25 variables, where only 2 columns are relevant (species & altitude):

https://filebin.net/z57rs5jrzdo0kwx4

I have imported the data into R studios using `data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)`, and my understanding so far is that I need to manipulate the data so that the number of species per given altitude is estimated. My best guess is to use a `.N` command to count the rows for a group, and then to use the `by` command to specify which column to compare the data with, but I'm unsure on how to implement this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(data.table) 

setDT(birds)[, .(count = uniqueN(Species)), by = Altitude]
```

It should produce a table with with species count by altitude. "birds" refers to what I named the data frame when I read it into R - you should change this if you have named your data something different.

Comment: That's amazing, thanks. Exactly the command I was looking for. How would I plot this data? `plot(birds$Altitude, birds$count)` isn't working at anticipated.

Comment: Your code to plot is correct, but it is not working because we never actually re-defined what "birds" is. The code I provided initially allows you to view a table using birds, but doesn't change what birds is. You can do this by adding "birds = " before the code: `birds = setDT(birds)[, .(count = uniqueN(Species)), by = Altitude]`